# Typescript: mapping object values with union types not working as expected

Tags: javascript, typescript

If I want to map object values where the values are all primitives, it's pretty straightforward:

```
type ObjectOf<T> = { [k: string]: T };

type MapObj<Obj extends ObjectOf<any>> = {
  [K in keyof Obj]: Obj[K] extends string ? Obj[K] : 'not string';
};

type Foo = MapObj<{
  a: 'string',
  b: 123,
}>; // Foo is { a: 'string', b: 'not string' }
```

However, when I have unions as object values, TS doesn't work as expected:

```
type AllPaths = '/user' | '/post';

type Props<Path extends AllPaths> = MapObj<{
  path: Path,
}>;

function Fn<Path extends AllPaths>({ path }: Props<Path>) {
  const path2: AllPaths = path;
}
```

I get the error:

```
Type 'Path extends string ? Path : "not string"' is not assignable to type 'AllPaths'.
  Type 'Path | "not string"' is not assignable to type 'AllPaths'.
    Type '"not string"' is not assignable to type 'AllPaths'.
      Type 'Path extends string ? Path : "not string"' is not assignable to type '"/post"'.
        Type 'Path | "not string"' is not assignable to type '"/post"'.
          Type 'string & Path' is not assignable to type '"/post"'.
```

Since each member of the union are strings, I expected the output of `MapObj` to remain unions of strings. How can I fix this?

TS Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2DAZgHgCoD4oC8UA3lANoDWAXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmAujdlAL4DcAKEGhIUALIBDMPASZZUCAA9gEFgBNasRCjRZJLELnxFigqOQDSUVlAoQQAe3TaEXV2UsdFKtZrqMrGxQAPweXlA0AOQsjsABzOxRQgLCotAAggA2WQAKksAAFlpEUQD0AK60EAxRUAA+UOVgjvTJaeDQuQyOYLSY+UU+qhpa2XkFxSYS0rKYZhZgkzSDhQA0gry4QoLoFSyoTI4sUABiLAOTw35jOau0uAAUpEtDvCs9fZdFuACUJOYoMhjvQoK9CgAmGjje6EMGTFKCIA

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2DAZgHgCoD4oC8UA3lANoDWAXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmAujdlAL4DcAKEGhIUALIBDMPASZZUCAA9gEFgBNasRCjRZJLELnxFigqOQDSUVlAoQQAe3TaEXV2UsdFKtZrqMrGxQAPweXlA0AOQsjsABzOxRQgLCotAAggA2WQAKksAAFlpEUQD0AK60EAxRUAA+UOVgjvTJaeDQuQyOYCUS0rKYZhZgBYU02XnjtAA0gry4QoLIjiz0UGA03b39pGNFNABEldUMR3zC6BUsqExrUABiLJj5RT6qGlpTb8W4ABT7cZ8bY9PoAShI5igq3W8QOhQATJMcr9+giFoIgA

Comment: @ŁukaszKarczewski I need to infer `Path` because other object values need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that even if you declare `type Props<Path extends AllPaths> = MapObj<{ path: Path, }>;` like this, it will only contain value `'/user' | '/post'`, but this knowledge may not be recognized by typescript static type checking, as it's type is `MapObj<{ path: Path, }>`  which is just MapObj of a js Object.

so simply just use `as Path` to compromise

```
function Fn<Path extends AllPaths>({ path }: Props<Path>) {
  const path2: AllPaths = path as Path;
}
```

or declare a type for PathObj like this:

```
type AllPaths = '/user' | '/post';
type AllPathObj = {
  path: AllPaths,
}

type Props<PathObj extends AllPathObj> = MapObj<AllPathObj>;

function Fn<PathObj extends AllPathObj>({ path }: Props<PathObj>) {
  const path2: AllPaths = path;
}
```